# Regrouping razor components in multiple subfolders under one namespace - Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I have a folder of components under the Shared directory.

```
>Shared
    +Components
        +MyComponentType1
            -MyComponentType1Base.razor
            -MyComponentType1Title.razor
        +MyComponentType2
            -MyComponentType2Base.razor
            -MyComponentType2Title.razor
    -MainLayout.razor
```

To include all the elements of the components subfolders i have to write all the using statements in the _Imports.razor

```
@using MyApp.Shared.Components.MyComponentType1
@using MyApp.Shared.Components.MyComponentType2
```

So my question is : Is there a way to regroup all the components in the subfolders in the Component directory so that i'd use only one using statement?

```
@using MyApp.Shared.Components
```

Answer (score 20):

The `@namespace` directive was added a few versions back. You can use this to override the default namespace of your components which is the folder path by default.

```
        +MyComponentType1
            -MyComponentType1Base.razor
            -MyComponentType1Title.razor
        +MyComponentType2
            -MyComponentType2Base.razor
            -MyComponentType2Title.razor
```

MyComponentType1Title.razor

```
@namespace MyComponents

<span>Component implementation</span>
```

MyComponentType2Title.razor

```
@namespace MyComponents

<span>Component implementation</span>
```

_Imports.razor

```
@using MyComponents
```